# Django wagtail {% slug url '<page>' %} page not found heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, wagtail

I have a small site made in Django (3.1.5) with Wagtail (2.11.3) and python 3.8.5

I am having a problem with my links when deploying my site to heroku. It is only a small portfolio site, so there are only 6 direct links to manage in the navbar. These page links work fine when ran on localhost, but I'm not sure what is happening when I deploy to heroku.

The links I use utilise 'slugurl' e.g:

```
<li class="menu-item">
                                    <a href="{% slugurl 'about' %}">About</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="menu-item">
                                    <a href="{% slugurl 'resume' %}">Resume</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="menu-item">
                                    <a href="{% slugurl 'projects' %}">Projects</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="menu-item">
                                    <a href="{% slugurl 'blog' %}">Blog</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="menu-item">
                                    <a href="{% slugurl 'contact' %}">Contact</a>
                                </li>
```

In the wagtail admin, I make sure that the slug matches the slugurl in the links e.g resume:
[image]

Also, when I go to the slug e.g mysite.com/resume the page loads fine and everything on it, statics, templates and added content through wagtail admin, etc works fine with no problems. However, when I click on the navbar which has `href = {% slugurl 'resume' %}` in the navbar raw HTML as above, I get a 404 error with the following in the address bar:

```
mysite.com/None/
```

If the page I am on is mysite.com/resume and I click a link in the navbar, it goes to:

```
mysite.com/resume/None/
```

Can anyone help me figure out how to resolve this? I'm sure it is a relatively minor fix that I am overlooking.

EDIT urls.py file for the project. Wagtail actually handles alot of the URLs:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import include, path
#from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin

from wagtail.admin import urls as wagtailadmin_urls
from wagtail.core import urls as wagtail_urls
from wagtail.documents import urls as wagtaildocs_urls
from wagtail.contrib.sitemaps.views import sitemap

#from wagtail_multi_upload.views import add as add_multiple_fix

from search import views as search_views

import debug_toolbar

urlpatterns = [
    path('django-admin/', admin.site.urls),
    #url(r"^multi-add-fix/", add_multiple_fix, name="add_multiple_fix"),

    path('admin/', include(wagtailadmin_urls)),
    path('documents/', include(wagtaildocs_urls)),

    path('djrichtextfield/', include('djrichtextfield.urls')),
    #path('comments/', include('django_comments.urls')),

    path('search/', search_views.search, name='search'),
    path('sitemap.xml', sitemap),
    path('__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),

]


if settings.DEBUG:
    from django.conf.urls.static import static
    from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

    # Serve static and media files from development server
    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

urlpatterns = urlpatterns + [
    # For anything not caught by a more specific rule above, hand over to
    # Wagtail's page serving mechanism. This should be the last pattern in
    # the list:
    path("", include(wagtail_urls)),

    # Alternatively, if you want Wagtail pages to be served from a subpath
    # of your site, rather than the site root:
    #    path("pages/", include(wagtail_urls)),
]
```

Comment: Can you show your urls.py file

Comment: Just to confirm: are you able to visit `mysite.com/resume` directly and get your resume page? And you don't have any other pages elsewhere in your page tree with the slug 'resume'?

Comment: Yes there are currently only 3 pages, home, about and resume. I can go to mysite.com/resume with no problems, loads fine. I have set the resume slug on the promotion tab of the page in wagtail admin. The only problem is when I click on a link in the navbar that it goes to whatever URL I'm on with /None appended to it